# Good Optimisations for an Interpreter

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, vector, interpreter

I'm building an interpreter for my own programming language as a hobby, using C++11. So far my interpreter can understand variables, expressions and print statements.

My interpreter is just a straight forward one that converts the source file into a list of tokens and the parser simply executes the tokens as it finds them in the C++ vector the tokens are stored in.

**Variable Lookup**

The way I lookup variables is, I get the length of the variable name and then I loop through the variables vector, only grabbing the first however many characters long the variable name is. When I find the variable name I grab the rest of the variable, the variable name and value are stored like this:

```
variable_name:variable_value
```

If the variable value is a string there are quotes around the variable value.

**Expression Evaluation**

When evaluating expressions, I first loop through the expression 1 character at a time and identify whether the character is a number, operator or a bracket. Then I combine the numbers together if the full number characters together if there is a number with more than 1 character.

When I do this I then add everything to a vector. I calculate whether the number of prepending minuses are even or not so that I know whether to replace them with a plus or a minus.

*Example:*

```
------------10  ->  becomes +10
because there are 12 minuses before the 10
```

Then I loop through the vector and count the number of left brackets, when I see a left bracket I store the value of the iterator in a variable. Then I start at that iterator and grab the contents of the inside of the bracket.

Then I loop through the inside of the bracket, first doing the division, then I loop again and do the multiply, then I do the subtraction and finally I do the addition. Then when the evaluation is done I remove the surround brackets around that part of the expression and store the value in the vector in the place of the left bracket.

*Example:*

```
(10 + -(2 * 4))
(10 + -(8))
(10 + - 8)
(10 - 8)
(2)
```

I wrote a hand-written lexer and parser. The lexer just does what you'd expect, it loops through the source code as a string, 1 character at a time and combines the characters together to identify each token.

The parser just compares the items in the token vector against a string, no regular expressions.

*Example of the parser*

Tokens vector looks like this:

```
[0] print
[1] string:"Hello World"
[2] sc
```

And the parser uses the string, `print string sc` to identify the meaning behind the order of the tokens.

Are there any good optimisations I can make to the way I'm doing things? I've never done Computer Science or any compiler courses so I'd appreciate any tips to improve my interpreter. I can show you the code if you want it, it's quite long though.

Comment: You need a more organized scheme for storing variables.  Probably some sort of a hash table, but you need to consider its structure in the event that your language has "scope" and hence variables need to be discarded when scope is exited.  There are several ways to handle scope in a symbol table.

Comment: @KerrekSB All the books I found were quite intimidating due to their length and every one I found assumed you had a Computer Science degree.

Comment: Well, that could be because it's a very difficult topic!

Comment: (And enjoy this effort.  It will, of course, not produce a "production quality" result, but you will learn a lot.)

Comment: @HotLicks could I just store the function the variable was declared in, beside the name? Like this, name:value:scope

Comment: It depends on the structure of your language.  It may be best to keep a separate symbol table for each function, but if your language has internal scopes (ie, nested `{}` sections) you need to handle that somehow.  Keep in mind that with any "scoped" language you need to search through all active scopes, from closest to most distant, in order.

Comment: "Are there any good optimisations I can make to the way I'm doing things?"  Only "good optimisations" are ones concerning pieces of code you can prove, or that are indicated by a profiler being problematic in terms of performance/memory. Otherwise you are wasting your time. Which is also suboptimal.

Comment: @BartoszKP do you know of any better ways than using the "time" command on OSX to time how long a command takes? Or is there any way to make the "time" command more accurate? It's difficult to see how much of an impact each part of my interpreter has on performance because the time command only shows to 3 decimal places.

Comment: @Francis Best would be to use a profiler - not sure if it's easy to get one for OSX. Manual measurements are usually very inaccurate. I imagine that it would be possible to create some set of unit-tests and time them, so you could have a result that's statistically significant.

Comment: You're just making it up as you go along. Your way of locating variables is madness: use a map for that; and that is no way to handle expressions either: neither optimal nor even correct. The expressions should already have been parsed into RPN, after which executing them is trivial. Nothing like what you've described whatsoever. Too broad to answer here. I suggest you do some proper research before continuing. You've started off on entirely the wrong track.

Comment: IMO right about now is the ***perfect*** time to read a book on interpreter/compiler design because you have encountered many of the problems an interpreter needs to overcome - so your mind is primed to soak up the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the biggest speedup you can get is (assuming a dynamically typed language):

1. Create a generic value object that can store a number, a string, a bool and other value types that you're going to handle in your language
2. Parse the expressions down to an AST

for example

```
struct Value {
    int type;
    enum {
       NUMBER = 1,
       STRING = 2
    };
    double doubleValue;         // Value in case it's a number
    std::string stringValue;    // Value in case it's a string

    Value(double x) : type(NUMBER), doubleValue(x) { }
    Value(const std::string& x) : type(STRING), stringValue(x) { }
};
```

Then an AST node can be a constant, a variable lookup, a unary operation or a binary operation:

```
struct ASTNode {
    virtual Value compute() = 0;
    virtual ~ASTNode() {}
};

struct ConstantNode : ASTNode {
    Value x;
    ConstantNode(Value x) : x(x) {}
    virtual Value compute() { return x; }
};

struct VariableNode : ASTNode {
    std::string name;
    VariableNode(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}
    virtual value compute() { return lookup(name); }
};

struct AdditionNode : ASTNode {
    ASTNode *a, *b;
    AdditionNode(ASTNode *a, ASTNode *b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    virtual Value compute() {
        Value av = a->compute();
        Value bv = b->compute();
        if (av.type == Value::NUMBER && bv.type == Value::NUMBER) {
            return av.doubleValue + bv.doubleValue;
        } else if (av.type == Value::STRING && bv.type == Value::STRING) {
            return av.stringValue + bv.stringValue;
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error("Type mismatch");
        }
    }
};
```

Which kind of pointer you want to use depends on how you plan to manage memory (naked pointers with nodes allocated in custom pools may be ok for a garbage collected approach, otherwise some reference counted smart pointer would work better).

With this approach when computing an expression you only do the needed operation (without redoing the parsing at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

I warmly recommend you this reading: http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/

A gentle but very well grounded introduction to the writing of compilers (and as a byproduct interpreters too).

Don't be stopped by the fact that it uses the Pascal language and was written more than 20 years ago: the concepts presented are universal.

Answer (score 0):

You should try expression evaluation made in a gpu-accelerated fashion. Using opencl or cuda or amp++. So big projects finish quicker. Ofcourse works for only independent expressions.